# how to view files of exteral hard drives connected via USB

Tags: external-hdd

i am wanting to connect a HDD via USB to view files, import and export files to and i cant seem to figure out how to get my machine to recognize any HDD

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? What happens when you connect your USB hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect an external HDD (For example Western Digital) via USB.

1)You will get an notification stating that the an external storage has been detected. something like this.
[image: Notification Image]

2. if that previous step doesn't work. You can check if whether the external HDD is getting detected or not using the "Disks" utility. All mount storage disks or devices will be displayed here.

Kindly check the above steps. If the issue still persists let me know.

Thanks
Senthamizh